# php in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, var

I have a the code below in my js which obviously works if the js is in the php file

```
filter: '<?php echo $my_cat>'
```

how can i make a variable maybe in the php file and pull it in my external js file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place this below code at the top part of your test.php page

```
<script>
var filter = '<?php echo $my_cat>';
</script>
```

and simply you can check it on your external.js file by alert

```
alert(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   function showme(){
   echo "HelloWorld";
}
?>    

<script type="text/javascript">
     var my_var = '<?php echo showme(); ?>' ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use short tags.

`<script>`

```
var filter = '<?=$my_cat?>';

</script>
```